# Removing email activation from restful_authentication plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I have a Rails app handling authentication with the restful_authentication plugin.

I'm experiencing problems with the email activation feature and before I deal with that I would like to just allow my users to register without having to go through the email activation process.

How do I disable the email activation feature.

Rails 2.2.3
Restful_authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app/models/user_observer.rb`, I replaced

```
UserMailer.deliver_signup_notification(user)
```

with

```
user.activate!
```

and it's working for me so far...

Comment: Yes, that's the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I think is regenerating the authentication:

Save your old code from User and Sessions  (from model and controller, if you coded something in that files), destroy the authentication and regenerate it

```
script/destroy authenticated user sessions
script/generate authenticated user sessions
```

The destroy script will delete the following files, be sure of backup it if you made any change.

```
rm  db/migrate/20100520071407_create_users.rb
rm  app/views/users/_user_bar.html.erb
rm  app/views/users/new.html.erb
rm  app/views/sessions/new.html.erb
rm  app/helpers/users_helper.rb
rm  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb
rm  test/fixtures/users.yml
rm  test/unit/user_test.rb
rm  test/functional/users_controller_test.rb
rm  test/functional/sessions_controller_test.rb
rm  config/initializers/site_keys.rb
rm  lib/authenticated_test_helper.rb
rm  lib/authenticated_system.rb
rm  app/controllers/users_controller.rb
rm  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
rm  app/models/user.rb
```

Comment: Thanks pablorc. Ideally I would have liked to not go that way. I'll see if anybody else knows another way.

Comment: You can remove the code yourself, but I find it slower and more difficult than regenerate it. Also, this way you aren't going to have useless code on your application.

I think it's the best option, but maybe I'm wrong. Let's wait